# MongoDB position operator $ doesn't work in java

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I have following json data in MongoDB and need to update status filed using traceId as a search key.

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59cd4ec748eecac127d4ed11"), 
    "mode" : "Email", 
    "text" : "template", 
    "subject" : "EIS Order Number EO17000988 - Notice Type SOA", 
    "scenario" : "SendCustomerNoticeGenericEvent", 
    "system" : "CIS", 
    "traceId" : NumberInt(676517451), 
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-09-27T19:20:10.860+0000"), 
    "recipients" : [
        {
            "status" : "Delivered", 
            "firstName" : " ", 
            "lastName" : " ", 
            "address" : "ao084x@att.com", 
            "type" : "to"
        }
    ], 
    "from" : {
        "firstName" : "AT&T Enterprise Notifications", 
        "lastName" : " ", 
        "address" : "blink@zld00826.vci.att.com"
    }
}
```

When I run my java code below with Spring boot framework, I always got error "The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query. Unexpanded update: recipients.$.status". However if I change position operator $ to number 0, the code worked. Why does the $ sign not work here? Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection("notifyHistoryDbmS");

BasicDBObject updateDoc = new BasicDBObject("$set", new BasicDBObject("recipients.$.status", status));
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject().append("traceId", Integer.valueOf(traceId));

UpdateResult statusUpdate = collection.updateOne(query, updateDoc);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is supported only by MongoDB's preview release (3.5.12+). See: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243

```
db.notifyHistoryDbmS.insertOne({ 
"_id" : ObjectId("59cd4ec748eecac127d4ed11"), 
"mode" : "Email", 
"text" : "template", 
"subject" : "EIS Order Number EO17000988 - Notice Type SOA", 
"scenario" : "SendCustomerNoticeGenericEvent", 
"system" : "CIS", 
"traceId" : NumberInt(676517451), 
"timestamp" : ISODate("2017-09-27T19:20:10.860+0000"), 
"recipients" : [
    {
        "status" : "Delivered", 
        "firstName" : " ", 
        "lastName" : " ", 
        "address" : "ao084x@att.com", 
        "type" : "to"
    }
], 
"from" : {
    "firstName" : "AT&T Enterprise Notifications", 
    "lastName" : " ", 
    "address" : "blink@zld00826.vci.att.com"
}
});
```

And then the following call results in that error message you saw.

```
db.notifyHistoryDbmS.updateOne(
   { "traceId": 676517451 },
   { "$set": { "recipients.$.status": "Sent" } },
   { "multi": true }
)
```

You've got two options:

- Update the elements of array *recipients* individually (you've tried this one already)
- Fetch the whole document, perform the desired modifications on it and then replace it

Answer (score 0):

$ is not working because you are using updateOne.

As per [mongo Java Driver](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/javadoc/?com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html#updateOne-org.bson.conversions.Bson-org.bson.conversions.Bson-) **updateOne** method takes 2 parameters

**filter** - a document describing the query filter, which may not be null.

**update** - a document describing the update, which may not be null. ***The update to apply must include only update operators***.

$ is defined as Array Operator used with update Method.

[Refer Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/#id1)